# does javascript require ';' at the end of a line of code?

Tags: javascript

I have seen and used javascript code that both has and omits the ';' from the end of statements. Are they required in some cases and not in others? If so can you give some examples, and if not what is the general standard, to use the ';' or to not...that..is the question??

Comment: This is a duplicate of _many_ [other SO questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+semicolon).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

JavaScript uses a (generally disliked) method called Semicolon Insertion, where it will allow you to omit semicolons.

The rules for where you can and cannot insert semicolons is extensive, and covered fairly well [here](http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons).

In general, do not rely on semicolon insertion. It is a poorly thought out feature and will hurt you before it helps you.

Not only should you always use semicolons, but you should also get in the habit of putting your `{` braces on the same line, as semicolon insertion can actually misinterpret what you meant.

For example, say I'm trying to return a javascript object from a function:

```
function f() {
    return { "a":"b", "c":"d" }    // works fine
}

function g() {
    return                         // wrong!!!
    {
        "a":"b",
        "c":"d"
    }
}
```

If I put the `{` on a new line (as I did in `g`), the return statement will actually have a semicolon inserted after it, destroying the meaning of what you were saying.

Overall, semicolon insertion is a poor feature and you should never rely on it.

Comment: The only part I disagree with is the "it is a poorly thought out feature". $10 says the guys that thought it out are smarter than you and me put together, and thought about it longer than you and me put together. The ES standard is written by top notch comp. sci.s. You are welcome to disagree with their decisions, but to say it's not thought out is a total misunderstanding of the standards procedure.

Comment: + At some point someone too smart decided that it would be cool to make VB Script from JavaScript and so that semicolon insertion was born... Road to programmer's hell is paved by such "cool" ideas ...

Comment: First to be right and linking to a good reference. I can only +1 though.

Comment: @davin, I agree that the guy who wrote it is *smart*, but it was definitely not well thought out. JavaScript was written by Brendan Eich, who was working at Netscape at the time. Under intense time pressure, he invented and wrote JavaScript in 10 days (more testament to his intelligence that he could throw a language together in 10 days). He's a smart guy, but he simply did not have time to think it through.

Comment: For practical purposes the `return [newline] { }` issue isn't really about semicolon insertion per se, because even if you adopt the practice of always putting a semicolon at the end of every statement that _won't help you with the return problem_.

Comment: @nnnnnn, it *is* the problem of semicolon insertion, because semicolon insertion is the reason it gets misinterpreted. You are right however that putting a semicolon at the end of every statement does nothing to help with that particular problem, thus why I advised to also not to get into the habit of putting `{`'s on a new line.

Comment: That's why I said "per se", which is of course Latin for "I'm pretentious". Wait, no, I mean that is why I said "for practical purposes", i.e., "what I as a programmer need to do to avoid the problem" - which _isn't_ inserting my own semicolons everywhere. (Though I do do that as a style preference.)

Comment: @nnnnnn – if you minify your code, you better not rely on automatic insertion. :-)

Comment: @RobG - I wouldn't use a minifier unless I was confident it could cope (i.e., do its own insertion as needed). Though as I already mentioned I choose to put semicolons everywhere anyway as a style preference, so I don't have to worry. (What does worry me is the way certain other guys on my team leave the semicolons out on a seemingly random basis that doesn't appear to have anything to do with whether the code works without them. And then they'll go ahead and put extra ones in after, e.g., function declarations.)

Comment: @nnnnnn — ok, but no one seemed to mention minifiers. For them to work properly with code missing semi-colons, they need to be able to accurately parse the code and either do insertion or leave newlines alone where appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Use <kbd>;</kbd> to mark the end of a statement. Javascript follows the syntactical theme set in C family languages, and <kbd>;</kbd> is the delimiter for the end of a statement.

What code have you seen that omits this?

If there's no more code in the block after a line, the <kbd>;</kbd> is technically optional. You should include it anyway.

Comment: `;` is (technically, bad style) optional in *many* more circumstances then that.

Answer (score 0):

Always use the semicolon, this makes the code easier to read. Right now I am not aware of any situation where it can be omitted.

Comment: There are more cases where it can be omitted than where it is necessary. (Assuming you're not in the habit of putting multiple statements on the same line, which does require semicolons but is hard to read.)