# javascript closure error

Tags: javascript, closures

I'm trying to do a setTimeout where I pass variables to the function being called within the setTimeout(). After some initial failures and then using The Google I found a site that described how to do it using closures. I pretty much followed the example but I keep getting an error message:

**missing ) after argument list**

This error message is being called on the setTimeout but as far as I can tell everything is closed off. Any help would be appreciated:

```
var textureAtlas = new Image()

function init() { 

    textureAtlas.src = "images/textureatlast1.png";
    var textureAtlasCoords = new Array("0,0", "100,0", "200,0", "300,0", "400,0", "500,0", "600,0");

    var canvas = document.getElementById('textureAtlas');

    if (canvas.getContext){

        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        for(var c=0; c<textureAtlasCoords.length; c++) {

            var thisCoord = textureAtlasCoords[c];
            var thisCoordSplit = thisCoord.split(",");
            var thisX = thisCoordSplit[0];
            var thisY = thisCoordSplit[1]; 

            var a = setTimeout(animate(){myFunction(ctx, textureAtlas, thisX, thisY); ctx=null, textureAtlas=null, thisX=null, thisY=null},1000);
        }

    } else {
        alert("Looks like your browser doesn't support HTML5");
    }

}

function animate() { 

    ctx.drawImage(thisImg,thisX,thisY, 1024, 451, 0, 0, 1024, 451);

}
```

Comment: In the setTimeout call, is 'animate' a typo? Or are you trying to call 'animate'?

Comment: What is with the `{...}` after animate?

Comment: If it helps I was working with the example given here: http://www.makemineatriple.com/2007/10/passing-parameters-to-a-function-called-with-settimeout

Comment: I was also referencing from this page: http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also:

```
function animate() { 

    ctx.drawImage(thisImg,thisX,thisY, 1024, 451, 0, 0, 1024, 451);

}
```

The context here will throw 'undefined', as the

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

will only be available within the scope of init.

You don't strictly need a ';' after the first line:

```
var textureAtlas = new Image()
```

However, it would be a very good idea, see: [does javascript require ';' at the end of a line of code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934208/does-javascript-require-at-the-end-of-a-line-of-code)

Comment: thanks for noticing the missing ;, that was a typo on my part.

Comment: as for the scope comment, I've initially tested with this code and it worked fine: imgDraw(ctx, thisImg); ... function imgDraw(ctx, thisImg) { ctx.drawImage(thisImg,0,0, 1024, 451, 0, 0, 1024, 451);}...are you saying animate() will throw an undefined because it is enclosed in setTimeout()?

Comment: I did wonder, actually, closures are a nightmare, and very little explained/ documented, I thought it might be available.  The trouble with closures is they may work for reasons you don't expect. :)

Comment: Seems like you were right, ctx is undefined. I'm new to closures and I feel like I am entering some of Dante's world here...I got rid of the error in the setTimeout - var a = setTimeout(function(){animate(textureAtlas, thisX, thisY);},400); I was misunderstanding the post I referenced...

Comment: Great, you'll find closures in various places- especially in foreach loops, where one wants to alter the thing over which one is iterating.  Don't. :)

Comment: So closures = bad, got it. : D

Comment: Haha. not quite, they're unavoidable and very useful, just had to understand!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely clear what you're trying to schedule, here.

I can tell you that setTimeout takes either a function literal or a function reference, like so:

```
setTimeout(nameOfMyFunction, 1000); // reference -- note, NO parentheses here

setTimeout(function() { // literal -- the function being executed is "anonymous"
        /* body of function here */
    },
    1000);
```

In the first syntax, it's important to note two things:

- the function `nameOfMyFunction` must be defined normally somewhere else;
- using this syntax, you can't pass any arguments to `nameOfMyFunction`.

If it's important to pass some args, then you can wrap the call in an anonymous function that passes them in, like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
        nameOfMyFunction(someArg, otherArg);
    },
    1000);
```

And it's not clear what `myFunction` is for. Is it your plan that `myFunction` prepares the drawing context for use by `animate`? Or is it some other, one-off operation that should just occur prior to `animate`?

Comment: (and others) I am trying to run an animation on a <canvas> off of a textureatlas, the animate function will receive x/y coordinates of the images on the texture atlas and a reference to the canvas to place it in.

Comment: To add some more detail - my understanding (which could be completely wrong) from the site I linked to in the comment above was that by using a closure I would be able to pass variables to the function called it setTimeout - in this case animate, as you can't pass variables through the function and adding them as a 3rd parameter to setTimeout raises problems in IE.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the word `function` on the `setTimeout`:

```
        var a = setTimeout(function animate() {
            myFunction(ctx, textureAtlas, thisX, thisY);
            ctx = null, textureAtlas = null, thisX = null, thisY = null
        }, 1000);
```

Comment: I was writing the setTimeout wrong: var a = setTimeout(function(){animate(textureAtlas, thisX, thisY);},400);

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
var a = setTimeout(animate(){myFunction(ctx, textureAtlas, thisX, thisY); ctx=null, textureAtlas=null, thisX=null, thisY=null},1000);
    }
```

By

```
var a = setTimeout(animate, 1000);
```

I don't know why you included `(){...}` after `animate`?

Comment: I am trying to pass variables to animate()